# how to change background color to grey

Tags: css

When you hover over the icon images the background color turns black. How do I change this to grey?

```
<h2>Contact Us Anytime!</h2>

        </div>
    </div> </div></section>
 <section  class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="spb_content_element col-sm-6  column_container">
        <div class="spb-asset-content">
         <section  class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="spb_icon_box col-sm-12">
        <div class="spb-asset-content">
        <div class="sf-icon-box sf-icon-box-left-icon sf-animation sf-icon- " data-animation="none" data-delay="0" style="background-color:;"><div class="sf-icon-cont cont-small sf-icon-float-none"><i class="fa-map-marker sf-icon sf-icon-small" style="color:;"></i></div><div class="sf-icon-box-content-wrap clearfix"><h3 style="color:;"></h3><div class="sf-icon-box-content" style="color:;">
<p> CT</p>
</div></div></div>
        </div>
    </div> </div></section>
```

Comment: What "icon images" are you talking about? Probably there is some form of css rule that gets applied when hovering over -whatever-. You can try to find out yourself: open your browsers development console (typically F12) and select the "elements" tab (or similar). In there you can see the styling rules applied to a specific element. Also you can switch to those rules applied when hovering with the mouse. What is the difference? That is your answer!

Comment: Post what have you tried so far.

Comment: check class .sf-hover on your css... This class will have background color black change that to grey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
.sf-hover .sf-icon-cont, .sf-hover .sf-icon-box-hr {
  background-color: #222!important;
}
```

To:

```
.sf-hover .sf-icon-cont, .sf-hover .sf-icon-box-hr {
  background-color: #8C8C8C!important;
}
```

***How to scrutinize CSS like a pro***

1) Right click on the HTML element -> Inspect element

2) Right click on the specific DOM -> Force element state -> :hover

[image]

3) * Play with the CSS on the right panel at real-time until you are satisfied.

***When life gets complicated***

Sometimes a sophisticated programmer decides to change the CSS on the fly using Javascript. So the second step won't help. To solve this issue you can hover the desired element and witness the DOM is being changed. I saw the DOM is being fulfilled with the `sf-hover` class so I added this class manually. That's how I was able to play with the CSS on the right side.

[image]